# Presenting UICollectionView from a UIButton swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

first, I hope I don't break any rules or make it long but I'm really stuck and spent the whole day about that so I would love to get help with that :).

Okay so I'm having a popped up view controller using Panmodel 3rd party and I've got a `UIButton` inside of a `UITableView` custom cell, now I want to present my custom calendar when the user press the button, now I followed Ray tutorial([Link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/10787749-creating-a-custom-calendar-control-for-ios#toc-anchor-003)) on how to do a custom calendar and it still doesn't work for me, for some reason when I press the button it just shows a clear view + freezes my screen :|, I'm going to post the code of my tableView setup + the cell of the UIButton, not going to post the code of the calendar because it's long and I don't want to spam, if needed I will post that :) once again thanks for the help really spent the whole day about it and found myself with no solution, so here's my code:

Code: TableViewVC:

```
    import UIKit
    import PanModal
       
    class FilterTableViewController: UITableViewController, PanModalPresentable {
        
        var panScrollable: UIScrollView? {
            return tableView
        }
        
        var albumsPickerIndexPath: IndexPath? //  indexPath of the currently shown albums picker in tableview.
        
        var datesCell = DatesCell()
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            setupTableView()
            //        registerTableViewCells()
            
        }
        
        override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
            super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
            //        tableView.frame = view.bounds
        }
        
        override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
            return .lightContent
        }
        
        // MARK: - View Configurations
        
        func setupTableView() {
            
            tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            
            tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
            tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
            tableView.allowsSelection = true
            
            tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
            tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 600
            
            tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
            tableView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        }
        
        func indexPathToInsertDatePicker(indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath {
            if let albumsPickerIndexPath = albumsPickerIndexPath, albumsPickerIndexPath.row < indexPath.row {
                return indexPath
            } else {
                return IndexPath(row: indexPath.row + 1, section: indexPath.section)
            }
        }
        
        // MARK: - UITableViewDataSource
        
        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            // If datePicker is already present, we add one extra cell for that
            if albumsPickerIndexPath != nil {
                return 5 + 1
            } else {
                return 5
            }
        }
        
        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            
            switch indexPath.row {
            case 0:
                
                let byActivityCell = UINib(nibName: "byActivityCell",bundle: nil)
                self.tableView.register(byActivityCell,forCellReuseIdentifier: "byActivityCell")
                let activityCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "byActivityCell", for: indexPath) as! byActivityCell
                activityCell.selectionStyle = .none
                
                return activityCell
                
            case 1:
                let byTypeCell = UINib(nibName: "ByType",bundle: nil)
                self.tableView.register(byTypeCell,forCellReuseIdentifier: "byTypeCell")
                let typeCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "byTypeCell", for: indexPath) as! ByType
                typeCell.selectionStyle = .none
                return typeCell
                
            case 2:
                let byHashtagsCell = UINib(nibName: "ByHashtags",bundle: nil)
                self.tableView.register(byHashtagsCell,forCellReuseIdentifier: "byHashtagsCell")
                let hashtagsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "byHashtagsCell", for: indexPath) as! ByHashtags
                hashtagsCell.selectionStyle = .none
                
                return hashtagsCell
                
            case 3:
                let byDatesCell = UINib(nibName: "DatesCell",bundle: nil)
                self.tableView.register(byDatesCell,forCellReuseIdentifier: "byDatesCell")
                let datesCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "byDatesCell", for: indexPath) as! DatesCell
                datesCell.selectionStyle = .none
                datesCell.datesTableViewCellDelegate = self
                
                return datesCell
                
            case 4:
                let byAlbumCell = UINib(nibName: "AlbumCell",bundle: nil)
                self.tableView.register(byAlbumCell,forCellReuseIdentifier: "byAlbumCell")
                let albumCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "byAlbumCell", for: indexPath) as! AlbumCell
                albumCell.configureCell(choosenAlbum: "Any")
                albumCell.selectionStyle = .none
    
                return albumCell
                
            case 5:
                let albumPickerCell = UINib(nibName: "AlbumsPickerTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
                self.tableView.register(albumPickerCell, forCellReuseIdentifier: "albumPickerCell")
                let albumsPicker = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "albumPickerCell", for: indexPath) as! AlbumsPickerTableViewCell
                
                return albumsPicker
                
            default:
                return UITableViewCell()
            }    
        }
        
        // MARK: - footer Methods:

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
            return getfooterView()
        }
        
        func getfooterView() -> UIView
        {
            let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 400))
            let applyFiltersBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 380, height: 35))
        
            applyFiltersBtn.center = footerView.center
        
            applyFiltersBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 12
            applyFiltersBtn.layer.masksToBounds = true
            applyFiltersBtn.setTitle("Apply Filters", for: .normal)
            applyFiltersBtn.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1957295239, green: 0.6059523225, blue: 0.960457623, alpha: 1)

                //        doneButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(hello(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
                
            footerView.addSubview(applyFiltersBtn)
        
            return footerView
        }
        
        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return 10
        }
        
        // MARK: TableViewDelegate Methods:
    
        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
            
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            
            // 1 - We Delete the UIPicker when the user "Deselect" the row.
            if let datePickerIndexPath = albumsPickerIndexPath,   datePickerIndexPath.row - 1 == indexPath.row {
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [datePickerIndexPath], with: .fade)
                self.albumsPickerIndexPath = nil
            } else {
                // 2
                //            if let datePickerIndexPath = albumsPickerIndexPath {
                //                tableView.deleteRows(at: [datePickerIndexPath], with: .fade)
                //            }
                albumsPickerIndexPath = indexPathToInsertDatePicker(indexPath: indexPath)
                tableView.insertRows(at: [albumsPickerIndexPath!], with: .fade)
                tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
            }
            
            tableView.endUpdates()
            
            if indexPath.row == 4 {
                let pickerController = CalendarPickerViewController(
                  baseDate: Date(),
                  selectedDateChanged: { [weak self] date in
                  guard let self = self else { return }
    
        //          self.item.date = date
                  self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 3, section: 0)], with: .fade)
                  })
    
                present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
        
        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
            if indexPath.row == 4  {
                return indexPath
            } else {
                return nil
            }   
        }    
    }
    
    extension FilterTableViewController: DatesTableViewCellDelegate {
        
        func didButtonFromPressed() {
            print("Button From is Pressed")
            let pickerController = CalendarPickerViewController(
              baseDate: Date(),
              selectedDateChanged: { [weak self] date in
              guard let self = self else { return }
    
    //          self.item.date = date
              self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 3, section: 0)], with: .fade)
              })
    
            present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    
        func didButtonToPressed() {
            print("Button To is Pressed")
            //TODO: Present our custom calendar
            let vcToDisplay = CalendarPickerViewController(baseDate: Date()) { (date) in
                
                self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 3, section: 0)], with: .fade)
            }
    
            self.present(vcToDisplay, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

custom cell code:

```
    import UIKit
    
    // MARK: - Class Protocols:
    
    protocol DatesTableViewCellDelegate { // a delegate to tell when the user selected the button:
        func didButtonFromPressed()
        func didButtonToPressed()
    
    }
    
    class DatesCell: UITableViewCell {
    
        @IBOutlet var fromDate: UIButton!
        
        @IBOutlet var toDate: UIButton!
        
        var datesTableViewCellDelegate: DatesTableViewCellDelegate?
    
        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            // Initialization code
            fromDate.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            toDate.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            
            fromDate.layer.borderWidth = 1
            toDate.layer.borderWidth = 1
    
            fromDate.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2005972862, green: 0.6100016236, blue: 0.9602670074, alpha: 1)
            toDate.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2005972862, green: 0.6100016236, blue: 0.9602670074, alpha: 1)
    
            fromDate.layer.masksToBounds = true
            toDate.layer.masksToBounds = true
            
            self.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
            self.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 15)
            self.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 15)
        }
    
        // MARK: - UIButton Methods:
        
        @IBAction func fromDateButtonIsPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
            datesTableViewCellDelegate?.didButtonFromPressed()
        }
        
        @IBAction func toDateButtonIsPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
            datesTableViewCellDelegate?.didButtonToPressed()
        }     
    }
```

Comment: You have a LOT going on here. I'd suggest: start with a "standard" table view controller and one cell (your `DatesCell`), and try to present a simple view controller from the cell's button tap. Once you get that working, try presenting your `CalendarPickerViewController`. Then add your other cell classes. Then implement whatever you're doing with `PanModalPresentable`. If that doesn't get you anywhere, try to create a [mre] and post it to GitHub (or similar).

Comment: @DonMag ye tbh had a feeling that its too much, but you know I downloaded their starter project and for some reason their code didnt work too lol

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, the problem was with the auto-layout, I changed the auto layout to be like this:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView.backgroundColor = .yellow

    
    view.addSubview(dimmedBackgroundView)
    view.addSubview(collectionView)
    
    var constraints = [
      dimmedBackgroundView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
      dimmedBackgroundView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
      dimmedBackgroundView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
      dimmedBackgroundView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
    ]
    
    constraints.append(contentsOf: [
      //1
      collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(
        equalTo: view.readableContentGuide.leadingAnchor),
      collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(
        equalTo: view.readableContentGuide.trailingAnchor),
      //2
      collectionView.centerYAnchor.constraint(
        equalTo: view.centerYAnchor,
        constant: 10),
      //3
      collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(
        equalTo: view.heightAnchor,
        multiplier: 0.5)
    ])

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)

//    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
//      dimmedBackgroundView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
//      dimmedBackgroundView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
//      dimmedBackgroundView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
//      dimmedBackgroundView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
//    ])
  }
```